# Sorting multiple columns in sheet depending on 1 column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying too sort 3 columns (column A B and C ) depending on the values in column A but i can't find a good example on how to achieve that. The number of rows varies.

First rows are headers:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chop out a lot of the code that is generated by recording a [Range.Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx). This is what is important.

```
With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    With .Resize(.Rows.Count, 3)
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    End With
End With
```

I'm not sure if the [.Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) is necessary. Your [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557) does not adequately describe the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx).

Comment: I'm trying to make it dynamic because the list will varie in length over time is the code you supplied to achive that? So Collum A B C and row count could be between 2 and max rowcount

Comment: So you clicked on the link I left you for the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) and read through that. What part of the CurrentRegion property are you having trouble with?

Comment: How to select the 3 collums i need 
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion 
tbl.Offset(1, 0).Resize(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, _ 
 MyCollums).Select

I guess my question is how to specify mulitiple collums in VBA syntax

Comment: @T Jasinski - That is not what you asked. Maybe you could get back to me once you actually figure out what you want and have demonstrated effort toward a solution.